# Как отправить письмо с несуществующего адреса?

Tags: email, java

Как отправить письмо с несуществующего адреса? Я использую `smtp mail.ru` и не могу отправить письмо с несуществующего адреса.

Comment: а какой смысл? Рассылать спам? Или что бы Вам назад не отписывались?

Comment: Я не собираюсь рассылать спам. Просто хочу такую штуку для себя сделать.

Comment: Тогда Вам нужен свой smtp сервер. В целом, любой сервер имеет право проверить адрес отправителя и отказать, если что то не так.

Comment: Я создал smtp с промежуточным сервером, ошибки теперь нет, но приходят письма только с реального адреса.

Comment: Может есть smtp, который позволяет отправлять письма с нереальных адресов?

Comment: >Может есть smtp, который позволяет отправлять письма с нереальных адресов?

Конечно. Азы спамерско-чайниковских технологий: берёте машину (vds, например), регистрируете домен, адрес, всё честно. Обработчиком почты для этого адреса делаете /dev/nul (на всякий случай, в общем-то этого и не нужно). Рассылаете, прибиваете домен, переносите машину на другой IP, повторяете...

Comment: Vds дорого стоит.

Comment: >Vds дорого стоит.

Ну, если 20-30 баксов в месяц это дорого (да и то для дурных целей можно дешевле найти), то путь один. Набираться ума и менять архитектуру задачи.

Comment: @Vladius001

> Может есть smtp, который позволяет отправлять письма с нереальных адресов?

smtp - это протокол. Он вообще ничего не ведает о реальности адресов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь дело вообще не в Java. SMTP, как верно указали в комментариях, вообще не ведает реален адресат или нет. Все дело в SMTP сервере. Если сервер сконфигурирован как [smtp-relay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP_relay), то он позволяет через себя отправить письмо от кого угодно. Обычно все юниксовые сервера по умолчанию при установке конфигурятся как open-relay и если админ не лох, то он первым делом прибьет это умолчание. А если лох, то :)

Comment: А вот такая мысль закралась в голову: не иметет ли автор вопроса в виду `From:` из конверта письма?